# Invocation of REST API in c# that is expecting File object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, restsharp

Our application has a WEB GUI that has an interface to accept the local file location and name. We have written a C# controller that is invoked while clicking submit button. The controller receives the file as HttpPostedFileBase.  From the controller, we are trying to invoke the REST API in C# that is expecting the File object as a request however we are unable to do so. The request is expecting the file and the request parameter is of form-data type. Any help to write a C# REST API client to invoke this REST service by passing the file.

below is my model code :
[PoSPRegistration model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWFJr.png)

in the above code image is received in HttpPostedFileBase object.

below is controller code :
[controller post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtCXw.png)

can't add image object in request.addfile method because it includes name and filepath

Comment: Please share examples of your current code, and perhaps explain where you are stuck. Also, consider reducing the scope of your question and keeping it one single question.

Comment: we have updated the question and also uploaded the snaps for the same

Comment: Please post code, not images of code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RestRequest` class in RestSharp has an overload of the `AddFile` method that takes a callback that is called to write data to a `Stream` object:

```
AddFile(string name, 
        Action<Stream> writer, 
        string fileName, 
        long contentLength, 
        string contentType = null)
```

You can use it like that to post data from a `HttpPostedFileBase`:

```
request.AddFile("pan", 
                stream => objmodel.doc_pan.InputStream.CopyTo(stream), 
                objmodel.doc_pan.FileName, 
                objmodel.doc_pan.ContentLength, 
                objmodel.doc_pan.ContentType);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)